# Fortran pointer to derived types and default initialisation

Tags: initialization, fortran, dynamic-allocation, derived-types

Fortran 2003 derived types have a nice feature of default initialization.

```
type TTest
  integer :: a
  integer :: b = 1
  integer, pointer :: p1, p2 => null()
end type TTest
```

then any declared variable of type (TTest) will have initialized  components b and p2 by default.

Consider  the following code:

```
type (TTest), dimension(:), pointer     :: varptr
type (TTest), dimension(:), allocatable :: varalloc
integer, parameter :: ndim = 1000

allocate(  varptr(ndim))
allocate(varalloc(ndim))
```

Can one be guaranteed that  all elements of varptr and varalloc will have initialized b and p2 members after allocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the standard requires that. Whenever you have a variable of that derived type, it will have those components initialized.

> F2008 4.5.4.6.3: If *null-init* appears for a pointer component, that
>   component in **any object of the type** has an initial association
>   status of disassociated (1.3) or becomes disassociated as specified in
>   16.5.2.4.
>
> F2008 4.5.4.6.6 : If *constant-expr* appears for a nonpointer component, that component in
>   **any object of the type** is initially defined (16.6.3) or becomes defined as specified in 16.6.5 with the value determined from
>   *constant-expr* ...